# Handle partial or summary object list returned by GET /models using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For a Resource Post,
How to handle following scenario.

GET /posts returns array with summary only (i.e. title, commentCount)
but GET /post/:id returns full object. (i.e. title, content, comments:[comment1, comment2] )

when app is loaded list of posts is visible on screen, I am calling **App.Post.find()** for fetching all Posts.
And when a item is clicked, if I try loading using **App.Post.find(1)**, It returns cached data item. One way is forcefully load complete Post from server.

**Edit**
Found relevant issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/51
I understand that its not semantically correct way to support REST.
But another usecase: Record may has been updated on server, I want to refresh it, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model's `.reload()` method to re-fetch it from the adapter. So in your route where you're getting stale data, instead of returning `this.store.find('post', 1)`, return `this.store.find('post', 1).reload()`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BookingSync/ember-data-partial-model was made to address this exact issue.